# Как сделать morphing анимацию частей SVG элемента по наведению мышки?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация, smil

Подскажите, есть ли возможность без подключения сторонних библиотек (GSAP / SVG-Morpheus) произвести изменения формы? Приведу пример:

```css
.game_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.btn_gamePlay {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: none;
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

.st7 {
  fill: #70203c;
}

.st8 {
  fill: #ef447e;
  stroke: #5e112d;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullImage" class="game_block">
  <button class="btn_gamePlay" type="button" title="Play">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 240 240">
      <path d="M171.5 182s11.5-.2 14.5-7.2 4.7-30 4.7-30l1.1-74.8s-.8-19.8-15.3-25.8-110.8 0-110.8 0S52.3 40 52 89.5s1.8 81.5 1.8 81.5 1 9.5 12.3 10.5 105.4.5 105.4.5z"
      fill="#ef457e" stroke="#5e102d" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="za_x5F_btn"/>
      <g id="za_hair">
        <path class="st18" id="eyebrow"
        d="M147 64.5s-5.9.8-7.4 2.5-1.3 2.6-1.3 2.6c2 0 7.5-2.5 10.1-4.1s-1.4-1-1.4-1z"/>
        <path id="main_hair"
        d="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z"
        fill="#1a1416" stroke="#171617" stroke-miterlimit="10">
          <animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s" calcMode="discrete" begin=fullImage.mouseenter
          to="M138.8 200s-.3.8-1.5 2-.9-4.9-2.3-5-3.4-15.8-4-5.3-1-3.8-1-3.8-2.6-3.3-4.8 4.3-2-3.1-3.5-1.5c-.8.9-2.5-2.7-2.5-1.8 1.3 41.2-2.6 14.7-3.5 13-1.8-3.3-.1-9.8-.5-8.5-.6 2.3-2.4 7.6-4.8 8.8s-.6-10.3-2-7.5-2.6 2.2-2.5 4.8-2.4-10.4-4.8-4.8-.9-5.4-2.8-3.3-5-2.8-6.8-6.5c-.3-1 .4 8.5-.8 7.3s-.1-5.8-1.3-3.8-4.3 2-4.3 2-.6-10.4-1.8-5-.4 3.3-.5 5.3c-.3 6.5-3.5 12.5-6.3-5.3-.2-1-1.3-5.5-1.3-4.5 3.1 31.8-4.8-1.8-5.8 2s-1 3.6-2.8 4.8-2.6-2.7-2.5-1.8c1.8 21.3-4.3 4.4-4.3 4.8s-5.3-18.3-4.9-11.2.9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8-.2 2-9 30.8-8.5 10.3.1-3.7-3-7.5-3-7.5s-1.9 23.3-2.8 16.5.8 7.6-.8 3.8.8-1 .8-1-2.8-25.8-3.8-27-1.6 24.1-2.3 23-3.1-24.1-4.8-21.5-1.5 15.9-2.3 13.8-2.5 9.8-3 5.8-2-8.1-4.3-9.3c-.7-.4-2.8-1-1.5 16.3.1 1.3-1.8 1.2-1.5 2.5 1.8 8.5-1.8 1.6-2.3.5-4.3-11.4.1-3-1.8-12-2.3-10.8-.3 6.9-.3 10.8 3.3-20-.9 12.8.3-12.3-6.9 2.4-4.1 14.1-4.8 7.8.1-5.6-.1-8.9-.5-3.3.2 14.3.7-2.8.7-2.8z">
          </animate>
          <animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s" calcMode="discrete" begin=fullImage.mouseleave
          to="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z">
          </animate>
        </path>
        <path id="curl_hair" d="M137.5 57.8s-.8-6.2-10.3-7.2-7.4-2.3-7.4-2.3"
        fill="none" stroke="#161516" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Необходимо реализовать чтобы по наведению курсора на обёртку "волосы" кнопки сползали за 2 сек. с позиции `1` в позицию `2`, при уходе курсора, всё в обратном порядке. (Количество контрольных точек `SVG` вроде как сохранил) [image: кнопка] Не могу понять где допускаю ошибку? Если `SMIL` событие повесить на `begin=za_hair.mouseenter`, то что-то происходит, но всё равно не то.

Comment: fill="freeze" dur="2s" calcMode="discrete"

Comment: Скорее всего где-то здесь накосячили

Answer (score 6, accepted):

После многодневных танцев с бубном над решением данной задачи и перечитыванию документации по SVG-анимациям (хотя это ничего не дало) я пришёл к мысли, что количество точек в обоих путях должно быть одинаковым и эти точки должны быть расположены определённым образом. К сожалению, об этом нигде не написано.

Чтобы все эти зависимости наглядно вам показать я приготовил такое изображение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На нём мы видим 14 красных и 28 синих точек на обоих картинках. Одинаковое количество красных и синих точек, а также их расположение очень важно для данного случая, т.к. иначе будет несоответствие количества точек и анимация такой, какую мы хотим, не получится.

Также как мне уже после написания моего ответа подсказал [Alexandr_TT](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/28748/alexandr-tt) нужно учитывать что:

> должны быть одни и те же команды у одинаковых от начала по счёту точек в начальном и в конечном виде (путях). Допустим у третьей точки первого пути стоит `C50` и у второго пути у этой же 3-ей точки должна быть команда `C...`

Это также означает, что начало (`M...`, `m...`) и конец путей должны совпадать.

Если этого всего не сделать, то будут ошибки. Чтобы эти ошибки наглядно увидеть достаточно в вашем коде изменить `calcMode="discrete"` в двух местах на `calcMode="linear"` и перенести `id="fullImage"` с внешнего `div`-а на `SVG` элемент. А вот `from="..."` указывать **не** нужно. Выглядеть это будет вот так:

```css
.game_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.btn_gamePlay {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: none;
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

.st7 {
  fill: #70203c;
}

.st8 {
  fill: #ef447e;
  stroke: #5e112d;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="game_block">
  <button class="btn_gamePlay" type="button" title="Play">
    <svg id="fullImage" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 240 240">
      <path d="M171.5 182s11.5-.2 14.5-7.2 4.7-30 4.7-30l1.1-74.8s-.8-19.8-15.3-25.8-110.8 0-110.8 0S52.3 40 52 89.5s1.8 81.5 1.8 81.5 1 9.5 12.3 10.5 105.4.5 105.4.5z"
      fill="#ef457e" stroke="#5e102d" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="za_x5F_btn"/>
      <g id="za_hair">
        <path class="st18" id="eyebrow"
        d="M147 64.5s-5.9.8-7.4 2.5-1.3 2.6-1.3 2.6c2 0 7.5-2.5 10.1-4.1s-1.4-1-1.4-1z"/>
        <path id="main_hair"
        d="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z"
        fill="#1a1416" stroke="#171617" stroke-miterlimit="10">
          <animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s" calcMode="linear" begin=fullImage.mouseenter
          to="M138.8 200s-.3.8-1.5 2-.9-4.9-2.3-5-3.4-15.8-4-5.3-1-3.8-1-3.8-2.6-3.3-4.8 4.3-2-3.1-3.5-1.5c-.8.9-2.5-2.7-2.5-1.8 1.3 41.2-2.6 14.7-3.5 13-1.8-3.3-.1-9.8-.5-8.5-.6 2.3-2.4 7.6-4.8 8.8s-.6-10.3-2-7.5-2.6 2.2-2.5 4.8-2.4-10.4-4.8-4.8-.9-5.4-2.8-3.3-5-2.8-6.8-6.5c-.3-1 .4 8.5-.8 7.3s-.1-5.8-1.3-3.8-4.3 2-4.3 2-.6-10.4-1.8-5-.4 3.3-.5 5.3c-.3 6.5-3.5 12.5-6.3-5.3-.2-1-1.3-5.5-1.3-4.5 3.1 31.8-4.8-1.8-5.8 2s-1 3.6-2.8 4.8-2.6-2.7-2.5-1.8c1.8 21.3-4.3 4.4-4.3 4.8s-5.3-18.3-4.9-11.2.9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8-.2 2-9 30.8-8.5 10.3.1-3.7-3-7.5-3-7.5s-1.9 23.3-2.8 16.5.8 7.6-.8 3.8.8-1 .8-1-2.8-25.8-3.8-27-1.6 24.1-2.3 23-3.1-24.1-4.8-21.5-1.5 15.9-2.3 13.8-2.5 9.8-3 5.8-2-8.1-4.3-9.3c-.7-.4-2.8-1-1.5 16.3.1 1.3-1.8 1.2-1.5 2.5 1.8 8.5-1.8 1.6-2.3.5-4.3-11.4.1-3-1.8-12-2.3-10.8-.3 6.9-.3 10.8 3.3-20-.9 12.8.3-12.3-6.9 2.4-4.1 14.1-4.8 7.8.1-5.6-.1-8.9-.5-3.3.2 14.3.7-2.8.7-2.8z">
          </animate>
          <animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s" calcMode="linear" begin=fullImage.mouseleave
          to="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z">
          </animate>
        </path>
        <path id="curl_hair" d="M137.5 57.8s-.8-6.2-10.3-7.2-7.4-2.3-7.4-2.3"
        fill="none" stroke="#161516" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Обратите внимание на то, что IE не поддерживает SVG анимацию.

И для того, чтобы всё это заработало правильно нужно пути написать соответствующим образом. Для того, чтобы это наглядно показать я изменил в пути `path` свойство `d="..."` и в элементах `animate` свойства `to="..."` на те точки, которые я описал выше. И всё заработало правильным образом.

### Правильное решение

```css
.game_block{position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; min-height: 100vh}
.btn_gamePlay
{
    width: 210px; height: 270px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="game_block">
    <button class="btn_gamePlay" type="button" title="Play">
    <svg id="fullImage" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 400 520" width="200" height="260">
        <rect x="22" y="81" width="360" height="320" rx="45" ry="45" fill="#f47" stroke="#c03" stroke-width="5"/>
        <path d="M23,437L3,373L7,353L3,118L10,55L29,37L172,1L233,2L289,9L372,49L394,80L398,117L397,381L382,443L372,354L360,362L357,276L345,304L338,197L329,207L328,174L321,174L312,143L300,149L277,110L266,111L259,89L247,83L220,129L216,112L198,184L192,158L176,231L164,218L133,254L119,311L100,295L83,359L68,342L56,381L40,371L22,403z" fill="#000" stroke="#555" stroke-width="6" stroke-linejoin="round">
            <animate
                attributeName="d"
                fill="freeze"
                dur="1s"
                calcMode="linear"
                begin="fullImage.mouseenter"
                restart="whenNotActive"
                to="M23,437L3,373L7,353L3,118L10,55L29,37L172,1L233,2L289,9L372,49L394,80L398,117L397,381L382,443L366,471L346,476L348,512L329,491L316,478L303,464L284,475L284,487L276,510L265,503L254,488L236,485L232,457L212,455L211,483L200,502L188,493L178,471L159,469L155,456L143,458L136,441L128,453L113,440L105,462L86,454L71,442L51,460z">
            </animate>
            <animate
                attributeName="d"
                fill="freeze"
                dur="1s"
                calcMode="linear"
                begin="fullImage.mouseleave"
                restart="whenNotActive"
                to="M23,437L3,373L7,353L3,118L10,55L29,37L172,1L233,2L289,9L372,49L394,80L398,117L397,381L382,443L372,354L360,362L357,276L345,304L338,197L329,207L328,174L321,174L312,143L300,149L277,110L266,111L259,89L247,83L220,129L216,112L198,184L192,158L176,231L164,218L133,254L119,311L100,295L83,359L68,342L56,381L40,371L22,403z">
            </animate>
        </path>
    </svg>
    </button>
</div>
```

Для того, чтобы это хорошо рассмотреть нажмите над snippet-ом ссылку «На всю страницу».

Comment: Ссылка на подобного рода анимацию (morphing) путей path - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/666958/28748

Comment: я дико извиняюсь, но по негласным правилам сетевого этикета, хорошо бы указывать источник ценной информации, которую используешь в своем ответе, тем более эту информацию нигде не найдешь в туториалах по smil Я имею ввиду фразу про идентичность типа узлов в стартовом и финальном патчах.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, указал теперь. Надеюсь тебе это теперь любо? ;-) Признавайся, а чего это ты сюда так часто заходишь? Нравится моё решение? :-)

Comment: нравится, нравится очень нравится :))) неточность нужно устранить - "Это также означает, что начало и конец путей должны совпадать." Правильнее это звучит так - узлы, одинаковых по счету должны быть одного типа `C`- `Q` `T` соответственно в обоих патчах

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, благо дарю! Подправил. Надеюсь теперь всем будет понятно.

Comment: @Bharata, спасибо, очень круто вышло. А скажи, пожалуйста, а как ты путь переделывал ?  Я имею ввиду из  d="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1. пришел к своему d="M23,437L3,373L7,353L3,118L10,55L29,37L172,1L233,2L289,9L372,49L с относительными координатами? Есть ли легкий путь решения данного вопроса? Или хотя бы как визуально смотреть отображение от точки к точки без постоянной перезагрузки браузера ?

Comment: @BlackStar1991 я не переделывал. Я взял каждую из картинок и отметил на ней точки как описано в ответе моём в обычном редакторе изображений растровых. Затем каждую из картинок отобразил на canvas и нажимал на точки мышкой по очереди на каждую точку. Так я получил массив из точек и затем между точками прописал команды SVG вручную. Второй ваш вопрос я не понял.

Comment: @Bharata,  спасибо! Идею понял.  Всем спасибо за помощь. Готовый результат можно посмотреть тут   https://codepen.io/BlackStar1991/pen/REjMjE

Answer (score 3):

Вот `рабочий вариант` того что вы здесь написали.

Ошибки:

**1. Надо поставить клик на `g` элемент (`begin="za_hair.mouseenter"`)**

**2. В `animate` надо указать начало анимации (`from="....."`)**

```css
.game_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.btn_gamePlay {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: none;
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

.st7 {
  fill: #70203c;
}

.st8 {
  fill: #ef447e;
  stroke: #5e112d;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullImage" class="game_block">
  <button class="btn_gamePlay" type="button" title="Play">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 240 240">
      <path d="M171.5 182s11.5-.2 14.5-7.2 4.7-30 4.7-30l1.1-74.8s-.8-19.8-15.3-25.8-110.8 0-110.8 0S52.3 40 52 89.5s1.8 81.5 1.8 81.5 1 9.5 12.3 10.5 105.4.5 105.4.5z"
      fill="#ef457e" stroke="#5e102d" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="za_x5F_btn"/>
      <g id="za_hair">
        <path class="st18" id="eyebrow"
        d="M147 64.5s-5.9.8-7.4 2.5-1.3 2.6-1.3 2.6c2 0 7.5-2.5 10.1-4.1s-1.4-1-1.4-1z"/>
        <path id="main_hair"
        d="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z"
        fill="#1a1416" stroke="#171617" stroke-miterlimit="10">
          <animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s" calcMode="discrete" begin="za_hair.mouseenter"
          from="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z"
          to="M138.8 200s-.3.8-1.5 2-.9-4.9-2.3-5-3.4-15.8-4-5.3-1-3.8-1-3.8-2.6-3.3-4.8 4.3-2-3.1-3.5-1.5c-.8.9-2.5-2.7-2.5-1.8 1.3 41.2-2.6 14.7-3.5 13-1.8-3.3-.1-9.8-.5-8.5-.6 2.3-2.4 7.6-4.8 8.8s-.6-10.3-2-7.5-2.6 2.2-2.5 4.8-2.4-10.4-4.8-4.8-.9-5.4-2.8-3.3-5-2.8-6.8-6.5c-.3-1 .4 8.5-.8 7.3s-.1-5.8-1.3-3.8-4.3 2-4.3 2-.6-10.4-1.8-5-.4 3.3-.5 5.3c-.3 6.5-3.5 12.5-6.3-5.3-.2-1-1.3-5.5-1.3-4.5 3.1 31.8-4.8-1.8-5.8 2s-1 3.6-2.8 4.8-2.6-2.7-2.5-1.8c1.8 21.3-4.3 4.4-4.3 4.8s-5.3-18.3-4.9-11.2.9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8-.2 2-9 30.8-8.5 10.3.1-3.7-3-7.5-3-7.5s-1.9 23.3-2.8 16.5.8 7.6-.8 3.8.8-1 .8-1-2.8-25.8-3.8-27-1.6 24.1-2.3 23-3.1-24.1-4.8-21.5-1.5 15.9-2.3 13.8-2.5 9.8-3 5.8-2-8.1-4.3-9.3c-.7-.4-2.8-1-1.5 16.3.1 1.3-1.8 1.2-1.5 2.5 1.8 8.5-1.8 1.6-2.3.5-4.3-11.4.1-3-1.8-12-2.3-10.8-.3 6.9-.3 10.8 3.3-20-.9 12.8.3-12.3-6.9 2.4-4.1 14.1-4.8 7.8.1-5.6-.1-8.9-.5-3.3.2 14.3.7-2.8.7-2.8z">
          </animate>
          <animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s" calcMode="discrete" begin="za_hair.mouseleave"
          from="M138.8 200s-.3.8-1.5 2-.9-4.9-2.3-5-3.4-15.8-4-5.3-1-3.8-1-3.8-2.6-3.3-4.8 4.3-2-3.1-3.5-1.5c-.8.9-2.5-2.7-2.5-1.8 1.3 41.2-2.6 14.7-3.5 13-1.8-3.3-.1-9.8-.5-8.5-.6 2.3-2.4 7.6-4.8 8.8s-.6-10.3-2-7.5-2.6 2.2-2.5 4.8-2.4-10.4-4.8-4.8-.9-5.4-2.8-3.3-5-2.8-6.8-6.5c-.3-1 .4 8.5-.8 7.3s-.1-5.8-1.3-3.8-4.3 2-4.3 2-.6-10.4-1.8-5-.4 3.3-.5 5.3c-.3 6.5-3.5 12.5-6.3-5.3-.2-1-1.3-5.5-1.3-4.5 3.1 31.8-4.8-1.8-5.8 2s-1 3.6-2.8 4.8-2.6-2.7-2.5-1.8c1.8 21.3-4.3 4.4-4.3 4.8s-5.3-18.3-4.9-11.2.9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8-.2 2-9 30.8-8.5 10.3.1-3.7-3-7.5-3-7.5s-1.9 23.3-2.8 16.5.8 7.6-.8 3.8.8-1 .8-1-2.8-25.8-3.8-27-1.6 24.1-2.3 23-3.1-24.1-4.8-21.5-1.5 15.9-2.3 13.8-2.5 9.8-3 5.8-2-8.1-4.3-9.3c-.7-.4-2.8-1-1.5 16.3.1 1.3-1.8 1.2-1.5 2.5 1.8 8.5-1.8 1.6-2.3.5-4.3-11.4.1-3-1.8-12-2.3-10.8-.3 6.9-.3 10.8 3.3-20-.9 12.8.3-12.3-6.9 2.4-4.1 14.1-4.8 7.8.1-5.6-.1-8.9-.5-3.3.2 14.3.7-2.8.7-2.8z"
          to="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z">
          </animate>
        </path>
        <path id="curl_hair" d="M137.5 57.8s-.8-6.2-10.3-7.2-7.4-2.3-7.4-2.3"
        fill="none" stroke="#161516" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Ну а если хотите анимировать при наведении на `div`. То здесь в помощь идет `js`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#fullImage').mouseenter(function(){
    document.getElementById("animEnter").beginElement();
  });
  
  $('#fullImage').mouseleave(function(){
    document.getElementById("animLeave").beginElement();
  });
});
```

```css
.game_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.btn_gamePlay {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: none;
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

.st7 {
  fill: #70203c;
}

.st8 {
  fill: #ef447e;
  stroke: #5e112d;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fullImage" class="game_block">
  <button class="btn_gamePlay" type="button" title="Play">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 240 240">
      <path d="M171.5 182s11.5-.2 14.5-7.2 4.7-30 4.7-30l1.1-74.8s-.8-19.8-15.3-25.8-110.8 0-110.8 0S52.3 40 52 89.5s1.8 81.5 1.8 81.5 1 9.5 12.3 10.5 105.4.5 105.4.5z"
      fill="#ef457e" stroke="#5e102d" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="za_x5F_btn"/>
      <g id="za_hair">
        <path class="st18" id="eyebrow"
        d="M147 64.5s-5.9.8-7.4 2.5-1.3 2.6-1.3 2.6c2 0 7.5-2.5 10.1-4.1s-1.4-1-1.4-1z"/>
        <path id="main_hair"
        d="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z"
        fill="#1a1416" stroke="#171617" stroke-miterlimit="10">
          <animate id="animEnter" attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s" calcMode="discrete" begin="mouseenter"
          from="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z"
          to="M138.8 200s-.3.8-1.5 2-.9-4.9-2.3-5-3.4-15.8-4-5.3-1-3.8-1-3.8-2.6-3.3-4.8 4.3-2-3.1-3.5-1.5c-.8.9-2.5-2.7-2.5-1.8 1.3 41.2-2.6 14.7-3.5 13-1.8-3.3-.1-9.8-.5-8.5-.6 2.3-2.4 7.6-4.8 8.8s-.6-10.3-2-7.5-2.6 2.2-2.5 4.8-2.4-10.4-4.8-4.8-.9-5.4-2.8-3.3-5-2.8-6.8-6.5c-.3-1 .4 8.5-.8 7.3s-.1-5.8-1.3-3.8-4.3 2-4.3 2-.6-10.4-1.8-5-.4 3.3-.5 5.3c-.3 6.5-3.5 12.5-6.3-5.3-.2-1-1.3-5.5-1.3-4.5 3.1 31.8-4.8-1.8-5.8 2s-1 3.6-2.8 4.8-2.6-2.7-2.5-1.8c1.8 21.3-4.3 4.4-4.3 4.8s-5.3-18.3-4.9-11.2.9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8-.2 2-9 30.8-8.5 10.3.1-3.7-3-7.5-3-7.5s-1.9 23.3-2.8 16.5.8 7.6-.8 3.8.8-1 .8-1-2.8-25.8-3.8-27-1.6 24.1-2.3 23-3.1-24.1-4.8-21.5-1.5 15.9-2.3 13.8-2.5 9.8-3 5.8-2-8.1-4.3-9.3c-.7-.4-2.8-1-1.5 16.3.1 1.3-1.8 1.2-1.5 2.5 1.8 8.5-1.8 1.6-2.3.5-4.3-11.4.1-3-1.8-12-2.3-10.8-.3 6.9-.3 10.8 3.3-20-.9 12.8.3-12.3-6.9 2.4-4.1 14.1-4.8 7.8.1-5.6-.1-8.9-.5-3.3.2 14.3.7-2.8.7-2.8z">
          </animate>
          <animate id="animLeave" attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s" calcMode="discrete" begin="mouseleave"
          from="M138.8 200s-.3.8-1.5 2-.9-4.9-2.3-5-3.4-15.8-4-5.3-1-3.8-1-3.8-2.6-3.3-4.8 4.3-2-3.1-3.5-1.5c-.8.9-2.5-2.7-2.5-1.8 1.3 41.2-2.6 14.7-3.5 13-1.8-3.3-.1-9.8-.5-8.5-.6 2.3-2.4 7.6-4.8 8.8s-.6-10.3-2-7.5-2.6 2.2-2.5 4.8-2.4-10.4-4.8-4.8-.9-5.4-2.8-3.3-5-2.8-6.8-6.5c-.3-1 .4 8.5-.8 7.3s-.1-5.8-1.3-3.8-4.3 2-4.3 2-.6-10.4-1.8-5-.4 3.3-.5 5.3c-.3 6.5-3.5 12.5-6.3-5.3-.2-1-1.3-5.5-1.3-4.5 3.1 31.8-4.8-1.8-5.8 2s-1 3.6-2.8 4.8-2.6-2.7-2.5-1.8c1.8 21.3-4.3 4.4-4.3 4.8s-5.3-18.3-4.9-11.2.9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8-.2 2-9 30.8-8.5 10.3.1-3.7-3-7.5-3-7.5s-1.9 23.3-2.8 16.5.8 7.6-.8 3.8.8-1 .8-1-2.8-25.8-3.8-27-1.6 24.1-2.3 23-3.1-24.1-4.8-21.5-1.5 15.9-2.3 13.8-2.5 9.8-3 5.8-2-8.1-4.3-9.3c-.7-.4-2.8-1-1.5 16.3.1 1.3-1.8 1.2-1.5 2.5 1.8 8.5-1.8 1.6-2.3.5-4.3-11.4.1-3-1.8-12-2.3-10.8-.3 6.9-.3 10.8 3.3-20-.9 12.8.3-12.3-6.9 2.4-4.1 14.1-4.8 7.8.1-5.6-.1-8.9-.5-3.3.2 14.3.7-2.8.7-2.8z"
          to="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z">
          </animate>
        </path>
        <path id="curl_hair" d="M137.5 57.8s-.8-6.2-10.3-7.2-7.4-2.3-7.4-2.3"
        fill="none" stroke="#161516" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Это конечно классно, но это не Morphing анимация. С таким же успехом, можно просто одному элементу display:block; display:none; давать Эффект +- также будет выглядеть

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Это от того что ваша картинка неправильно сделано.

Comment: А что там не правильного ? Вроде как количество контрольных точек не менялось

Comment: @BlackStar1991 ну это уже редактором если не ошибаюсь надо сделать, в этом я не спец

Answer (score 2):

Вот еще один вариант. Здесь уже в `animate` надо задать `values`.

Но здесь опять плавности не будет. И это уже от вашего `svg`. Надо поменять сому картинку `svg`.

```css
.game_block {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.btn_gamePlay {
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: none;
  transition: 0.2s all;
}

.st7 {
  fill: #70203c;
}

.st8 {
  fill: #ef447e;
  stroke: #5e112d;
  stroke-width: 0.5;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}
```

```html
<div id="fullImage" class="game_block">
  <button class="btn_gamePlay" type="button" title="Play">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    viewBox="0 0 240 240">
      <path d="M171.5 182s11.5-.2 14.5-7.2 4.7-30 4.7-30l1.1-74.8s-.8-19.8-15.3-25.8-110.8 0-110.8 0S52.3 40 52 89.5s1.8 81.5 1.8 81.5 1 9.5 12.3 10.5 105.4.5 105.4.5z"
      fill="#ef457e" stroke="#5e102d" stroke-miterlimit="10" id="za_x5F_btn"/>
      <g id="za_hair">
        <path class="st18" id="eyebrow"
        d="M147 64.5s-5.9.8-7.4 2.5-1.3 2.6-1.3 2.6c2 0 7.5-2.5 10.1-4.1s-1.4-1-1.4-1z"/>
        <path id="main_hair"
        d="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z"
        fill="#1a1416" stroke="#171617" stroke-miterlimit="10">
          <animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s"
          values="M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z;M138.8 200s-.3.8-1.5 2-.9-4.9-2.3-5-3.4-15.8-4-5.3-1-3.8-1-3.8-2.6-3.3-4.8 4.3-2-3.1-3.5-1.5c-.8.9-2.5-2.7-2.5-1.8 1.3 41.2-2.6 14.7-3.5 13-1.8-3.3-.1-9.8-.5-8.5-.6 2.3-2.4 7.6-4.8 8.8s-.6-10.3-2-7.5-2.6 2.2-2.5 4.8-2.4-10.4-4.8-4.8-.9-5.4-2.8-3.3-5-2.8-6.8-6.5c-.3-1 .4 8.5-.8 7.3s-.1-5.8-1.3-3.8-4.3 2-4.3 2-.6-10.4-1.8-5-.4 3.3-.5 5.3c-.3 6.5-3.5 12.5-6.3-5.3-.2-1-1.3-5.5-1.3-4.5 3.1 31.8-4.8-1.8-5.8 2s-1 3.6-2.8 4.8-2.6-2.7-2.5-1.8c1.8 21.3-4.3 4.4-4.3 4.8s-5.3-18.3-4.9-11.2.9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8-.2 2-9 30.8-8.5 10.3.1-3.7-3-7.5-3-7.5s-1.9 23.3-2.8 16.5.8 7.6-.8 3.8.8-1 .8-1-2.8-25.8-3.8-27-1.6 24.1-2.3 23-3.1-24.1-4.8-21.5-1.5 15.9-2.3 13.8-2.5 9.8-3 5.8-2-8.1-4.3-9.3c-.7-.4-2.8-1-1.5 16.3.1 1.3-1.8 1.2-1.5 2.5 1.8 8.5-1.8 1.6-2.3.5-4.3-11.4.1-3-1.8-12-2.3-10.8-.3 6.9-.3 10.8 3.3-20-.9 12.8.3-12.3-6.9 2.4-4.1 14.1-4.8 7.8.1-5.6-.1-8.9-.5-3.3.2 14.3.7-2.8.7-2.8z" calcMode="discrete" begin="za_hair.mouseenter">
          </animate>
          
          <animate attributeName="d" fill="freeze" dur="2s"
          values="M138.8 200s-.3.8-1.5 2-.9-4.9-2.3-5-3.4-15.8-4-5.3-1-3.8-1-3.8-2.6-3.3-4.8 4.3-2-3.1-3.5-1.5c-.8.9-2.5-2.7-2.5-1.8 1.3 41.2-2.6 14.7-3.5 13-1.8-3.3-.1-9.8-.5-8.5-.6 2.3-2.4 7.6-4.8 8.8s-.6-10.3-2-7.5-2.6 2.2-2.5 4.8-2.4-10.4-4.8-4.8-.9-5.4-2.8-3.3-5-2.8-6.8-6.5c-.3-1 .4 8.5-.8 7.3s-.1-5.8-1.3-3.8-4.3 2-4.3 2-.6-10.4-1.8-5-.4 3.3-.5 5.3c-.3 6.5-3.5 12.5-6.3-5.3-.2-1-1.3-5.5-1.3-4.5 3.1 31.8-4.8-1.8-5.8 2s-1 3.6-2.8 4.8-2.6-2.7-2.5-1.8c1.8 21.3-4.3 4.4-4.3 4.8s-5.3-18.3-4.9-11.2.9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8-.2 2-9 30.8-8.5 10.3.1-3.7-3-7.5-3-7.5s-1.9 23.3-2.8 16.5.8 7.6-.8 3.8.8-1 .8-1-2.8-25.8-3.8-27-1.6 24.1-2.3 23-3.1-24.1-4.8-21.5-1.5 15.9-2.3 13.8-2.5 9.8-3 5.8-2-8.1-4.3-9.3c-.7-.4-2.8-1-1.5 16.3.1 1.3-1.8 1.2-1.5 2.5 1.8 8.5-1.8 1.6-2.3.5-4.3-11.4.1-3-1.8-12-2.3-10.8-.3 6.9-.3 10.8 3.3-20-.9 12.8.3-12.3-6.9 2.4-4.1 14.1-4.8 7.8.1-5.6-.1-8.9-.5-3.3.2 14.3.7-2.8.7-2.8z;M137.5 57.8s-8.5 14.3-9.8 15.5.4-3.4-.9-3.5-6.3 10.8-6.9 21.3-1.1-3-1.1-3-.5-5.4-2.7 2.1-3.4 20.6-4.9 22.2c-.8.9-1.2.1-1.3-.9-.2-1-.8-1.9-1.7-2.2-.5-.2-.7.1-1.1 1.4-.6 2.3-.1 2.9-2.4 4s-5.1 1.1-6.5 3.9-2.5 1.2-2.4 3.8.8 4.2-1.6 9.8-1.6 6.4-3.4 8.6-3.4 1.4-3.6.3.8-1.4-.4-2.7-3.3-3.5-4.4-1.4-3.7 10.4-3.7 10.4 1.3-4.9.1.4-.1 7.3-1 9.1-1.9 2-2.7 1.4-2.5-5.4-3.4-4.9-2.2 3.1-3.2 6.9-.3 5.5-2.1 6.7-3.3-2.4-4.2-2.6-2.9 3.1-2.9 3.4-4.4 4.9-3.9 12 .9 9.7.1 10-2.8-4.1-3.6-7.8-5-14.2-3.4-21.3c1.5-6.7-1.3-85.2-.7-92.4.8-9.4 1.9-19.4 4.4-21.8 3.5-3.3 4.8-5.3 14-7.9s38.6-10.8 52-9.8 30.9.4 42.6 5.9 18.3 9 18.3 9c4.4 4.4 12.6 1.6 13.6 25.8s.1 96.3-.1 98.3-3.5 19.9-3.5 19.9c-2.9 6-3.3-1.8-3.3-1.8s-.3-22-1.9-25.4-2.8-.4-2.8-.4-1.4.9-2.3-5.9.6-20-.9-23.9-2.6 4.4-2.6 4.4-.5 4.4-1.5 3.1-2-35.3-2.6-36.4-.4-1-2 1.6-1.3-7.9-2-10-2.8.6-3.3-3.4-1-7-3.3-8.1c-.7-.4-1.3-.2-1.7.2-1 .9-2.5.4-3.1-.7-2.5-4.7-6.7-12.6-8-12.5-1.8.1-2.3 0-2.6.6s-1.8-2.3-2-6.1c-.1-1.7-1.3-2.4-2.4-2.7-1.2-.3-2.3-1.1-3.2-2 .1-.3-.1-.5-.1-.5z" calcMode="discrete" begin="za_hair.mouseleave">
          </animate>
        </path>
        <path id="curl_hair" d="M137.5 57.8s-.8-6.2-10.3-7.2-7.4-2.3-7.4-2.3"
        fill="none" stroke="#161516" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </g>
    </svg>
  </button>
</div>
```

Вот пример другой `svg` картинки. и здесь уже та же самая анимация, с идентичными параметрами работает правильно.

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 288 288">
<linearGradient id="PSgrad_0" x1="70.711%" x2="0%" y1="70.711%" y2="0%">
  <stop offset="0%" stop-color="rgb(95,54,152)" stop-opacity="1" />
  <stop offset="100%" stop-color="rgb(247,109,138)" stop-opacity="1" />
</linearGradient>
<path fill="url(#PSgrad_0)">
 
    <animate id="animation-to-check" repeatCount="indefinite" fill="freeze" attributeName="d" dur="5s"
     
    values="M37.5,186c-12.1-10.5-11.8-32.3-7.2-46.7c4.8-15,13.1-17.8,30.1-36.7C91,68.8,83.5,56.7,103.4,45
    c22.2-13.1,51.1-9.5,69.6-1.6c18.1,7.8,15.7,15.3,43.3,33.2c28.8,18.8,37.2,14.3,46.7,27.9c15.6,22.3,6.4,53.3,4.4,60.2
    c-3.3,11.2-7.1,23.9-18.5,32c-16.3,11.5-29.5,0.7-48.6,11c-16.2,8.7-12.6,19.7-28.2,33.2c-22.7,19.7-63.8,25.7-79.9,9.7
    c-15.2-15.1,0.3-41.7-16.6-54.9C63,186,49.7,196.7,37.5,186z;
     
     
    M51,171.3c-6.1-17.7-15.3-17.2-20.7-32c-8-21.9,0.7-54.6,20.7-67.1c19.5-12.3,32.8,5.5,67.7-3.4C145.2,62,145,49.9,173,43.4
    c12-2.8,41.4-9.6,60.2,6.6c19,16.4,16.7,47.5,16,57.7c-1.7,22.8-10.3,25.5-9.4,46.4c1,22.5,11.2,25.8,9.1,42.6
    c-2.2,17.6-16.3,37.5-33.5,40.8c-22,4.1-29.4-22.4-54.9-22.6c-31-0.2-40.8,39-68.3,35.7c-17.3-2-32.2-19.8-37.3-34.8
    C48.9,198.6,57.8,191,51,171.3z;
     
    M37.5,186c-12.1-10.5-11.8-32.3-7.2-46.7c4.8-15,13.1-17.8,30.1-36.7C91,68.8,83.5,56.7,103.4,45
    c22.2-13.1,51.1-9.5,69.6-1.6c18.1,7.8,15.7,15.3,43.3,33.2c28.8,18.8,37.2,14.3,46.7,27.9c15.6,22.3,6.4,53.3,4.4,60.2
    c-3.3,11.2-7.1,23.9-18.5,32c-16.3,11.5-29.5,0.7-48.6,11c-16.2,8.7-12.6,19.7-28.2,33.2c-22.7,19.7-63.8,25.7-79.9,9.7
    c-15.2-15.1,0.3-41.7-16.6-54.9C63,186,49.7,196.7,37.5,186z  "/>
 
    </path>
 
</svg>
```